# Google Sheets VLOOKUP replacing both blank & N/A! cells

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

I am using a vlookup to reference another sheet which could return one of 3 values:

a) name
b) #N/A!
c) blank cell

I want my formula to return "Not on System" instead of b), "None Listed" instead of c), and the name for a)

So far I have 
=iferror(vlookup(P2,'Other Sheet'!B:V,21,FALSE),"Not on System")

Which solves for a) & b) - but not for c). Does anyone know what I can add to enter "None Listed" if the outcome is a blank cell?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will solve you problem:

```
=IF(
   ISBLANK(
    IFERROR(VLOOKUP(P2,'Other Sheet'!B:V,21,FALSE),"Not on System")),
    "None Listed",
    IFERROR(VLOOKUP(P2,'Other Sheet'!B:V,21,FALSE),"Not on System")
)
```

For more universal explanation look at this picture + an array formula (then you wil have formula only in one cell):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi this would fix your requirement:

=IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(VLOOKUP(P2,'Other Sheet'!B:V,21,FALSE)),"Not on System",VLOOKUP(P2,'Other Sheet'!B:V,21,FALSE)),"None Listed")

I have built it with the vlookup mentioned in your thread.
So you can directly implement this formula